# Problem with displaying my images with Nuxt

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js, nuxt3, custom-error-pages

I am currently working on the routing of my Nuxt project and I've been having some issues with nesting certain folders to create a routing that looks like this: "/PageAccueil/PricingPage/Checkout123".

The problem is that when I try to place my "PricingPage" folder inside my "PageAccueil" folder and then try to place the Checkout123.vue file inside it, all the images placed in my component no longer appear. I receive a 404 error in my console, which tells me that the image cannot be found, even though the path is correct.

However, I don't have this error when I use an image from Google, because Nuxt is able to find the image. But I think it's unable to find the images on my local machine.

Does anyone have any idea what could be causing this problem? For your information, I am using Nuxt 3.

@Robolivier, could you try to respond?

Comment: If you could provide an example of your codes on how you run it and also the structure of your pages that would be helpful. 

Comment: We need te see the image paths so we can tell you if it's actually the right paths, because it really sounds like it's not. If you're able to load absolute url images, but not relative url assets, then your path is likely the wrong one.

Answer (score 0):

Static images are best to be placed into `/public` directory and then referenced absolutely from there. Alternatively you can use `/assets` and then reference using `~/assets/...`

Check the docs for details: https://nuxt.com/docs/getting-started/assets